# use column value as column name mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get all users in 5 KM radius. here is my table structure

```
id| location
-------------
1|  26.851791,75.781810
2|  26.860729,75.7633127
3|  34.057811,-84.239125
```

I write a query to separate the location according to `lat` and `long`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( location, ',', 1 ) AS lat, SUBSTRING_INDEX( location, ',', -1 ) AS lng
FROM `users_test`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Which work fine and I got results as following

[image]

then I write a query to get all the users who are in 5KM Radius according to the following blog.

https://www.marketingtechblog.com/calculate-distance/

```
SELECT *,SUBSTRING_INDEX( location, ',', 1 ) AS lat, SUBSTRING_INDEX( location, ',', -1 ) AS lng,(((acos(sin(("26.851791"*pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos(("26.851791"*pi()/180)) * cos((`lat`*pi()/180)) * cos((("75.781810"- `lng`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance
FROM `users_test`
WHERE distance >= "5"
```

but I am getting following error.

> #1054 - Unknown column 'lat' in 'field list'

can anyone tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: you can't use aliases in field list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't refer to a column alias in the same `SELECT` clause. You need to move it into a subquery. And you can't refer to an alias in the `WHERE` clause of the same `SELECT`, you need to use `HAVING`.

```
SELECT *, (((acos(sin(("26.851791"*pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos(("26.851791"*pi()/180)) * cos((`lat`*pi()/180)) * cos((("75.781810"- `lng`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance
FROM (SELECT *, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( location, ',', 1 ) AS lat, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( location, ',', -1 ) AS lng
      FROM users_test) x
HAVING distance > 5
```

I strongly suggest you fix your table design to put the latitude and longitude in their own columns, instead of having to split on comma every time.

Comment: getting following erro  #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Fixed. I gave the subquery an alias.